# How to Switch Keyboard Languages in Debian 10

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu, configuration, language

I am a multi lingual person I have installed Debian 10 on RPi4 I I have configure Libre write with right hand and left hand languages then I have install all available fonts for my chosen languages by Synaptic Package Manager As in Ubuntu you can select your desire language from top right hand corner by clicking on "en" or "fr" icons and in window you can achieve this task by simply pressing Alt+Shift from your keyboard. I have read in other post you can switch languages by pressing Super+Space but in my case combination is not working

[image]

Now the 2nd language is installed but I can't figure out how to switch in between languages keyboard layout

[image]

Can someone please let me know the process

Comment: Are you using Gnome, Xfce, ...? Which one?

Comment: I'm not sure how can I find out?

Comment: I have install standard Debian 64bit OS recommended for Raspberry pi 4 B+ (Full desktop).